# SQL combining tables to single rows

Tags: sql, join, union

A problem with combining tables into single rows.

TABLE GAMES:

| ID | player1_ID | player2_ID | des |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 23 | 68 | something |
| 82 | 34 | 23 | whatever |
| 302 | 13 | 34 | mmmmmmmm |

TABLE PLAYERS:

| ID | alias |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | Jeex |
| 34 | Jack |
| 68 | Jill |
| 13 | John |

The key I start my query with is one of the Player ID's.

**I want to show all the games that Player ID=23 is playing in. That can be as Player1 or Player2.**

I also tried with a cross table,

TABLE CROSS:

| ID | player_ID | game_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 11 |
| 2 | 68 | 11 |
| 3 | 34 | 82 |
| 2 | 23 | 82 |
| 3 | 13 | 302 |
| 3 | 34 | 302 |

but without results.

The issue is that I want the *aliasses* and *other players data* of in the output as well as *some extra board data*, without having to deal with multiple rows per game.

**So, the requested output would be like:**

| game_ID | player1_ID | player2_ID | des | alias1 | alias2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 23 | 68 | something | Jeex | Jill |
| 82 | 34 | 23 | whatever | Jack | Jeex |

I tried several approaches, but can't figure this out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please share the "several approaches" (and full details on table structure, with some sample data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join `games` to 2 copies of `players`, so that you can get both aliases and filter `games` in the `WHERE` clause to get the rows only for the player that you want:

```
SELECT g.*, 
       p1.alias alias1,
       p2.alias alias2 
FROM games g
INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player1_ID
INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player2_ID
WHERE ? IN (g.player1_ID, g.player2_ID)
```

Change `?` to the player's id that you want.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the possibility of aliassing table names. Top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT g.*, p1.alias AS alias1, p2.alias AS alias2 FROM games g
 JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.player1_ID
 JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.player2_ID
```